# Capture JSON sent from PHP in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am posting the 2 dropdown list values to php through XMLHttpRequest which I can see are OK in firebug after pressing the send button. With those values sent to php, in php i make a query and store results to an array, then I echo `json_encode ($queryresult)`. And now the problem is  I am trying to get that array in the first page that sent the values  with javascript but no result, but i can see the echoed array through firebug in network xhr response :

[image: XHR Response]

Html form: (the selects are filled correctly through another js function)

```
  <form> 
  <table style="width:300px"> 

<h2>Consulta Fichas Técnicas:</h2>
<tr>
<td>Marca:</td>
<td> <select id="se" name="select_marca">
  <option value="0"> --Selecciona Marca--</option>
</select></td>
<td>Combustible:</td>
<td><select id="combus" name="combust">
  <option value="0">  --Selecciona Combustible-- </option>
</select></td>

<td>
  <input id="botonenvia" type="button" value="Enviar Consulta" onClick="sendInfo()"/>
  <!-- <input  type="submit"  />-->
</td>

</tr>

</table>



</form>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Javascript XHR part:

```
<script   type="text/javascript" >
var ajaxWhatcha;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) ajaxWhatcha = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else if (window.ActiveXObject) ajaxWhatcha = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");


  function sendInfo() {

  ajaxWhatcha.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (ajaxWhatcha.readyState == 4) {
        document.getElementById("botonenvia").value = "Enviado "; 
      }
    }

ajaxWhatcha.open("GET", "consulta.php?thingsIsend=" + document.getElementById("se").value +"& thingsIsend2=" + document.getElementById("combus").value, true);


    ajaxWhatcha.send(null); // Send it

}

</script>
```

Now i need to capture that respones i tried this Jquery with no results , maybe i should capture it somehow with another xhr?:

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "consulta.php",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      async: false,

     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
     //var data = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
     document.write('entering success'); //doesnt print
     console.log('entering succes');
     alert(xhr.status);alert(data); //no alert prints
      for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        alert(data[i].modelo);
      }console.log(data);
     }

    });

</script>
```

Also tried with no results:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
```

Php simply echo json_encodes the array with the query results. Sorry for the length of the post

Comment: Try to parse the **JSON** in the success function like `data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);` before accessing the data.

Comment: Tried it, apparently nothing changes.

Comment: Try checking the console, if there are any responses being given.

Comment: console.log=(data); under success doesnt print anything

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
jQuery.ajax ({
    url: "consulta.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: null,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){

        // May not require this line 
        data = $.parseJSON(data)
    }
});
```

Comment: apparently no change, still cant see my alert window

Comment: Call is going to consulta.php and json is returning back?

Comment: Please check firebug to see if there is any js error otherwise please share the code through e-mail

Comment: error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(xhr.responseText);
      }

Add this line to see what error are you getting - definitely you are getting some error.

Comment: Call is going to consulta.php and json is returning back?

Comment: that error as the last line of the $ajax doesnt show anything should i place it in another place? by the way big thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54825/discussion-between-codebased-and-user3470815).

Comment: jQuery.ajax ({
    url: "consulta.php",
    type: "GET",
    data: null,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){

        // May not require this line 
        data = $.parseJSON(data)
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { 

alert(xhr.status); 
alert(xhr.responseText); 
} 
});

Comment: check my profile, and below go to reputation tab, youll se i only gave 1 upvote

Comment: perhaps i didnt downvote anybody yet so i dont have the badge for the first downvote, look http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7/critic?userid=3470815

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your PHP is returning valid JSON (check with JSONLint.com) you should only need to do the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "consulta.php",
       async: false,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
       },
       error: function() {
           console.log("error");
       }
    });
</script>
```

cant see any issue with the jQuery

Comment: No output of that console.log

Comment: Now that you edit, i get that error from console log